# How can i fix this type of error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: check_email is not defined onblur"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Amateur</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js">
        function check_email()
        {
            var email=$("#txtEmail").val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                type:"POST";
                url:"index.php";
                data:"email="+email,
                success:function(msg)
                {
                    $("#chkEmail").html(msg);
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <label for="txtEmail">E-mail:</label>
        <input id="txtEmail" name="email" type="email" onblur="return check_email()">
    <label id="chkEmail" for="txtEmail"></label>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        $user='root';

        $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=class;charset=utf8',$user);

        $email=$_POST['email'];

        $stmt=$pdo->prepare('SELECT email from tbl_users WHERE email=:email LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email));

        if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
        {
            echo 'E-mail already use.';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'E-mail not use.';
        }

    }

    ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am still a starter in PHP and JQuery I want to know how to fix this type of error? I check it from firebug. The flow is that after the user done typing the email it will check automatically from the database if it exist or not. And the expected output does not show in my page.

Comment: `$(#chkEmail).html(msg);` should be `$("#chkEmail").html(msg);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes on selectors, seperating parameters in the ajax function with semicolons and not comma's etc.

```
    function check_email() {
        var email=$("#txtEmail").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"index.php",
                data: {email: email},
                success:function(msg) {
                    $("#chkEmail").html(msg);
                }
            });
            return false;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another `<script>` tag, it's not right way to add js source files and also code in the same tags.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script>
        function check_email()
        {
            var email=$("#txtEmail").val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                type:"POST";
                url:"index.php";
                data:"email="+email,
                success:function(msg)
                {
                    $("#chkEmail").html(msg);
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js">
    function check_email()
    {
        var email=$("#txtEmail").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"post",
            url:"index.php",
            data:"email="+email,
            success:function(msg)
            {
                $("#chkEmail").html(msg);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you need to change semi-colons (;) between arguments to commas (,) also

Comment: all semi colons to commas? what $(#id) ?

Comment: i mean that in jquery you need to put ids in $("#id") or $('#id')
not all semi colons, only where they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type:"post";
            url:"index.php";
            data:"email="+email,
    success:function(msg)
                    {
                        $(#chkEmail).html(msg);
                    }
             **TO**
$.ajax(
        {
            type:"POST",
            url:"index.php",
            data:{email:email},
success:function(msg)
                {
                    $('#chkEmail').html(msg);
                }
```

Comment: @BrainedWashed now check if this not work then check by using Firebug or Chrome Javascript Console check whether there is still error of Javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      var checkEmail= function()
        {
            var email=$("#txtEmail").val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                type:"POST",
                url:"index.php",
                data:"email="+email,
                success:function(msg)
                {
                    $("#chkEmail").html(msg);
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <label for="txtEmail">E-mail:</label>
        <input id="txtEmail" type="email" onblur="javascript:checkEmail();">
    <label id="chkEmail" for="txtEmail"></label>

</form>
</body>
```

add to `onblur="javascript:checkEmail();` and i made a function a bit different, declared it to var.

Answer (score 0):

Place your jquery source on a separate script. Make sure you put a closing tag (not a self-closing tag) for script.

Use commas for arguments, not semi-colon.

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_email()
    {
        var email=$("#txtEmail").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"POST",
            url:"index.php",
            data:"email="+email,
            success:function(msg)
            {
                $("#chkEmail").html(msg);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```